# Password prompt on login only, not on lock screen

Tags: password, xfce, lock-screen, screensaver

I'd like to only be prompted for my password on login, as I thought I had indicated on setup. But when I open my laptop lid, I'm prompted again.

Is it possible to eliminate the Suspend (on battery) and Switch Off Display (plugged in) password prompt?

I've also been prompted, I think, when the screensaver kicks in, but I've been closing the lid so it doesn't get to the screensaver.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. Open **`Settings`**
2. Navigate to **`Privacy` → `Screen Lock`**
3. Disable **`Lock Screen on Suspend`**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I'm running Xubuntu and I don't find Privacy under Settings (or so far, anywhere else).

I just noticed this message: "Xfce Power Manager is not configured to handle laptop lid events. Your computer may not be locked when you close the lid."

But it seems locked enough to warrant a password prompt. {sigh}

Comment: @Hulda Can you check if `gnome-screensaver-preferences` is in `/usr/bin`? If so, can you run it and take a screenshot of the window and include it in the original post?

Comment: Haven't found a Notepad (like Leafpad) yet, so here's what I found in Terminal for Gnome:

 gnome-font-viewer                     systemd-id128
 gnome-help                            systemd-inhibit
 gnome-keyring                         systemd-machine-id-setup
 gnome-keyring-3                       systemd-mount
 gnome-keyring-daemon                  systemd-notify
 gnome-language-selector               systemd-path
 gnome-thumbnail-font                  systemd-resolve
 gnome-www-browser                     systemd-run

Doesn't look like any screen saver preferences

Comment: What a mess my reply is! I was hoping Shift-Enter would give me a line feed : (

Comment: Honestly have no idea on this, sorry, can't help you. :(

Comment: works for me 22.04 , thanks.