# Kubuntu 20.04 screen lock on suspend sometimes fails; allows resume from suspend without login (security issue)

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, security, lock-screen

I just opened my laptop (Thinkpad X1 Carbon gen 6), which resumed straight to the desktop with no login required. This is obviously a security issue, since if anyone had physical access to my laptop during this time, they could open up straight to my email, etc.

I felt the bottom of the laptop beneath the CPU to see if maybe the laptop simply hadn't entered suspend, but it was cool (which would not be the case even if this laptop was idling).

Closing the lid just after this put the laptop in suspend, and upon resume I did have to login, as normal -- but the fact that this isn't working properly is definitely a security issue.

Any suggestions?

Edit: The problem persists. It just happened again. If anyone has a better idea where I should seek support for this issue, feel free to make suggestions.

Comment: What is the ["grace period"](https://imgur.com/TOCLUog) set to? Any apps that could prevent the system from going to sleep (download/torrent, etc...)

Comment: "Allow unlocking without password for: 5 seconds"

Comment: As for apps, no torrent or other download apps running. Only thing I can think of that could maybe interfere is KeePassXC, but in my experience, if there are unsaved changes and you try to lock the terminal or suspend, the app doesn't prevent this, and simply pops up a dialogue saying there are unsaved changes.

Comment: I have the opposite problem.. I want to enable automatic login after suspend. I do have it on boot.   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432646/autologin-option-in-user-settings-does-not-persist-22-04/1433649#1433649

Comment: solved here for me, the opposite, so maybe you can toggle settings, privacy, lock screen on suspend and see if it fixes things.   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1389431/password-prompt-on-login-only-not-on-lock-screen