# If I have automatic boot login, should that also obviate the need for password at suspend resume?

Tags: suspend, 22.04

theory question not seeking a solution.
I have achieved auto login on reboots.
but I am still required to put a password in when I logout and resume.
is this the expected behaviour?
and if so, what do I need to do to get no password requirement from the logout/login or suspend/resume login screen?

5.15.0-48-generic
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
GNOME Shell 42.4

Comment: it is possible automatic login does not apply to the logout/suspend and resume.. then I have heard about passwordless login, perhaps that is the answer , or hint .

Comment: It'll depend how setup...  I have a Lubuntu 22.04 setup that subsequently uses LXQt as desktop, `sddm` as login & `xscreensaver` as the lock (ie. post hibernate/suspend). To get auto-login that is achieved via `sddm` change; as lock is done via `xscreensaver` the suspend/resume-from-hibernate (*no password tweak*) is done via `xscreensaver` tweak.  Ubuntu 20.04 using GNOME uses GNOME &  `gdm3` and I don't know if `gdm3` can be tweaked, but if it can't, I know it can be replaced for greeter/lock functions  (*that I've done*).

Comment: thanks, I am almost there for hibernate, and I would assume it works as boot does for me. tweaks not accessible as of now gnome-shell-extension-manager is not opening up. you've given me hints to search on though, ta

Comment: still have to login from hibernate resume though.

Comment: solved here.... https://askubuntu.com/questions/1389431/password-prompt-on-login-only-not-on-lock-screen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Password prompt on login only, not on lock screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1389431/password-prompt-on-login-only-not-on-lock-screen)

Comment: thanks, I already had it and posted it here.

Answer (score 2):

Already solved here....

[Password prompt on login only, not on lock screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1389431/password-prompt-on-login-only-not-on-lock-screen)

simply settings, privacy (not power or display)

untoggle lock screen on suspend.

so simple, yet so not obvious.

Comment: also I thought it had gone back to password prompt, not so, that is a new problem on suspend resume related to "authentication is required to update smart data", and I am just escaping from that without *complying*